# LG K410 - проблемы с режимом usb-модем на Ubuntu Mate 16.04 x64

Tags: ubuntu, модемы

После включения на LG K410 режима usb-модем устанавливается соединение, которое пропадает через ~15 секунд. При этом модем все ещё виден системой.
Установил wvdial, ниже приведен wvdial.conf. Вызов *sudo wvdial* к подключению не приводит. *usb_modeswitch -H* тоже не помогает.
Какие ещё есть варианты?

```
serega@serega-work:~$ ls /dev/ttyACM*
/dev/ttyACM0

serega@serega-work:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1004:61fe LG Electronics, Inc. Optimus Android 
Phone [USB tethering mode]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

serega@serega-work:~$ dmesg | tail -n100 | grep usb
[ 2571.713560] usbhid 1-6:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[ 2576.845572] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 12
[ 2577.220020] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[ 2577.369018] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=61fe
[ 2577.369021] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2577.369024] usb 1-6: Product: LGE Android Phone
[ 2577.369026] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: LGE
[ 2577.369028] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 9TKF59PZTCZLROPF
[ 2577.371923] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-6, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:1c:48:43:5d:26
[ 2577.901158] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 enp0s29f7u6i3: renamed from usb0
[ 2598.302714] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 2598.331999] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 enp0s29f7u6i3: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:1d.7-6, CDC Ethernet Device
[ 2598.744027] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[ 2598.896771] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=6300
[ 2598.896774] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[ 2598.896777] usb 1-6: Product: USB Charge Only Interface
[ 2598.896779] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: LGE
[ 2598.897310] usbhid 1-6:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[ 2600.023682] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 2600.436025] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
[ 2600.585237] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=61fe
[ 2600.585240] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2600.585243] usb 1-6: Product: LGE Android Phone
[ 2600.585245] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: LGE
[ 2600.585247] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 9TKF59PZTCZLROPF
[ 2600.588197] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-6, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:1c:48:43:5d:26
[ 2601.120022] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 enp0s29f7u6i3: renamed from usb0
[ 2631.236049] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 15
[ 2631.274701] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 enp0s29f7u6i3: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:1d.7-6, CDC Ethernet Device
[ 2916.668031] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[ 2916.820806] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=6300
[ 2916.820810] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[ 2916.820813] usb 1-6: Product: USB Charge Only Interface
[ 2916.820815] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: LGE
[ 2916.821336] usbhid 1-6:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[ 2923.236089] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ 2923.652026] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 2923.801055] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1004, idProduct=61fe
[ 2923.801059] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2923.801062] usb 1-6: Product: LGE Android Phone
[ 2923.801064] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: LGE
[ 2923.801066] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 9TKF59PZTCZLROPF
[ 2923.805724] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-6, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:1c:48:43:5d:26
[ 2924.337772] cdc_ether 1-6:1.3 enp0s29f7u6i3: renamed from usb0
----------------------------------------------------------------------
wvdial.conf
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = USB Modem
Baud = 460800
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
Password = megafon
Username = megafon
Auto Reconnect = on

serega@serega-work:~$ sudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
AT+CGREG?
+CGREG: 2, 1, "0520", "019D277E", 6
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
NO CARRIER
--> No Carrier!  Trying again.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
NO CARRIER
--> No Carrier!  Trying again.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
AT+CSQ
NO CARRIER
--> No Carrier!  Trying again.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
+CSQ: 8, 99
OK
------------------------------------------------------
usr/share/usb_modeswitch/1004:61fe
DefaultVendor=0x1004
DefaultProduct-0x6300

TargetVendor=0x1004
TargetProduct=0x61fe

serega@serega-work:~$ usb_modeswitch -H
No default vendor/product ID given. Abort
```

Answer (score 0):

В файл /etc/network/interfaces добавляем

```
auto enp0s29f7u6i3
iface enp0s29f7u6i3 inet dhcp
```

и перезапускаем сеть

```
sudo service networking restart
```